# Rails 5: rails db:migrate or rake db:migrate in heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, migration

since the release of rails 5.0 it is suggested to use
`rails db:migrate` 
My question is, when using heroku, which one should I use: 
`heroku run rails db:migrate` or `heroku run rake db:migrate` ?

Answer (score 1):

Please use heroku run rake db:migrate

[Check On heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-rails5#migrate-your-database)

Comment: It will be more helpful to to put some relevant content from the attached page here since links can change or break in future.